# Applescript to check for the existence of a file

Tags: applescript

I record radio programs during the night and then run an applescript to rename the files.  I have the script working unless there is no file named that I am attempting to call and rename.  Here is my code that is working:

```
set Yesterday to (current date) - (24 * 60 * 60)
set myYesterday to (date string of Yesterday)
set y to year of date myYesterday
set m to month of date myYesterday
set d to day of date myYesterday

set newMyYesterday to m & " " & d & ", " & y as text

set newHourOne to "Recording1 - " & newMyYesterday & " - Hour 1.mp3"
set theFile to (POSIX file "/Users/Administrator/Recordings/Recording1.mp3") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set the name of file theFile to newHourOne
end tell

set newHourTwo to "Recording2 - " & newMyYesterday & " - Hour 2.mp3"
set theFile to (POSIX file "/Users/Administrator/Recordings/Recording2.mp3") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set the name of file theFile to newHourTwo
end tell
```

Can someone please show me how to check to see if the individual file ("Recording1.mp3" or "Recording2.mp3") exist before trying to rename the individual file?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if exists file theFile then
    # do stuff
else
    display dialog "File not found" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end if
```